# Entering Brazil by air, leaving by land, will I be denied entry?

Tags: visas, brazil, denial-of-entry, proof-of-onward-travel

I've just read this question

[Travelling to Brazil without return ticket](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7708/travelling-to-brazil-without-return-ticket)

which suggests that I will need to prove that I am leaving Brazil before the 90-day visa expires. If I was planning on leaving Brazil overland, how does this work? How do I prove my plans to go to Argentina by bus? Will I be denied entry, unless I have an air ticket out of there?

Comment: I entered Brazil by air before travelling around SA by bus and flying home from Peru. You won't have any issues

Comment: Show them your air ticket out of Argentina.  You'll need it to prove onward travel when entering Argentina anyway.

Comment: I just launched a blog while traveling the world. And I wrote an article about that very topic: [Proof of onward travel or how to avoid it](http://www.grownupplayground.com/proof-onward-travel-avoid/). I hope it helps a few of you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally the burden is on you to prove onward travel.  Whether that be air or land.

Some case examples:

- I flew into Canada, and was going to bus to the USA.  I had to prove I had a bus ticket to leave
- I flew into Argentina, with the intention of busing around South America.  I had a return ticket to the UK.  This was fortunate, as it at least showed I planned on leaving at some point.  I was still then able to bus out.  I was required to prove this even before getting on the plane TO Argentina  - airlines can be fined if they let you onboard without proof of onward travel AND a valid visa / entry permit.

Therefore, you will likely need either a plane ticket out of Brazil which you will then 'decide' not to use, or will need to purchase a bus ticket in advance.

At a push, having a hotel booked in Argentina might be enough, as it's evidence you're leaving.  I've been told by people that Canada is satisfied enough with such proof, given you could go to Niagara Falls and then walk across, although I've not put that to the test.

Comment: Yes I was hoping that showing something like a hotel booking in a different country or a bus ticket out would do the trick.

Comment: In general I think the level of scrutiny you get depends simply on the particular immigration officer you get.

Comment: I think being confident in your plans should be enough.  A bus ticket and hotel confirmation print-out should be plenty.  Remember also, that they will almost certainly not check any reservations you present.

Comment: However, see also this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7708/travelling-to-brazil-without-return-ticket in which the poster was denied boarding by the *airline* since he could show neither a Brazilian visa nor a return ticket.

Comment: @nibot - yes, if you read the question, that's the very question the OP referenced when asking this.  And as I said, it's the airline's responsibility (they can be fined) to check, so yes, they could deny you boarding.

Answer (score 3):

The majority of international airlines sell return tickets for a price similar to that of one-way tickets (see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_booking_ploys#Throwaway_ticketing) on the subject), so you wouldn't lose any money by buying a return ticket initially.

For example, a flight from [London to Rio](http://www.kayak.com/flights/LON-RIO/2014-03-12/2014-03-19) costs $886 when purchased both-ways and $1117 when purchased [one way](http://www.kayak.com/flights/LON-RIO/2014-03-12), saving you $231 and lots of headache when trying to prove your good intentions to the authorities.