# Getting into Brazil with an onward ticket from another country

Tags: visas, brazil, proof-of-onward-travel, german-citizens

I'm planning to travel around the world starting in the end of July. My first flight is Frankfurt to Rio de Janeiro (via Heathrow) on July 26th. I am a German citizen and I want to enter Brazil without a formal visa. According to Brazilian immigration policy, this is possible for up to 90 days.

However, since I'm planning to leave by land, I do not have an onwards ticket for leaving Brazil. I have already taken a look at [Entering Brazil by air, leaving by land, will I be denied entry?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8245/entering-brazil-by-air-leaving-by-land-will-i-be-denied-entry), however my situation is somewhat different.

The British Airways ticket that I am going to fly into Brazil with also includes a flight from Santiago de Chile to Auckland on October 26th. This is more than 90 days from the date at which I am going to enter Brazil.

I also have a plane ticket from Antofagasta (CL) to Santiago on October 20th, which is within the 90-day-limit of entering Brazil. However, I'm worried that this evidence of my intent to leave Brazil within the allowed time is too weak for Brazilian border police.

Will the tickets I have purchased be sufficient to convince border police that I intend to leave Brazil within the allotted time or will I still have to buy some other ticket out of Brazil?

**Update** Everything went well for me last July, the border police just stamped me in and didn't event want to see my plane tickets. Not sure if I was just lucky or if they really don't care that much. Note that this was during the world youth day celebrations in Rio, so they might have been optimizing for immigration throughput...

Comment: Slip a bank note into your passport before passing the border control. That will help to convince the border police ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the discussions on [similar forums](http://www.travbuddy.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=41353) the burden of proof of onward travel is on you and whether or not to accept something as proof of onward travel would be entirely in the discretion of the Immigration officer when you arrive.

Now if you are concerned about whether or not your ticket from Santiago to Auckland is sufficient proof of onward travel you should take a look at the tips given in [Living the Dream](http://www.livingthedreamrtw.com/2009/02/proof-of-onward-travel-part-1.html) blog on the subject.

Excerpt from the article:

> From the comment below: *FROM TFA: If you have a ticket leaving from another country within the period of your visa activity (say 90 days later on a 90 day visa) then this should be sufficient proof in most cases as you have to be out of one country to catch a flight in another.*

Comment: From TFA: _If you have a ticket leaving from another country within the period of your visa activity (say 90 days later on a 90 day visa) then this should be sufficient proof in most cases as you have to be out of one country to catch a flight in another._ Although I'm not sure how authoritative this is, it sounds like good advice and fits my situation. I think you should add this quote to your answer.

Answer (score 4):

We just had a problem leaving London Heathrow. The AlItalia check-in would not allow us to leave without a ticket which showed we were leaving Brazil, even though we had a flight booked out of Peru within the three month period. It meant we had to buy a plane ticket out of Brazil before we checked in.

Answer (score 3):

You will not need a visa to visit Brazil for up to 90 days (see [Brazil visa requirements for German citizens](http://isletravel.visaheadquarters.com/visa_info_plugin.php)).

However, some countries will not issued a visa unless a return ticket is also purchased. If I were you I would check with you closest Brazil Embassy [list of addresses here](http://www.embassyconsulates.com/brazil/brazil-embassy-in-germany.html) just to make sure and explain you situation.

Comment: @nkket Why does he have to check with an American Embassy ?

Comment: to be 100% sure about the visa. Best thing to do.

Comment: @rikket but the OP is German, not American...

Comment: oh sorry my bad I meant to say Brazil not American embassy. I am the one who needs american embassy not OP. Edited

Answer (score 0):

A bit later to help you but it might help others.

Brazil isn't that rigorous when it comes to imigrantion, all depends on your citizenship.

As Germany had been so friendly to Brazilians, Brazil just reply the same rules and treatments. If you look like a tourist, have enough money, everything will be fine.

But citizens of countries that aren't so friendly to Brazilians, will surely taste the same "unfriendness".

Anyway in extremes cases you may do have a second ticket and pay additional costs to rebook and change the city/country, or request a refund (if the air company allows it).

(I'm sure that Brazilian Polícia Federal won't deny anyone's entry because if you planned to cross borders by land, just don't lie).