# Do I need a return flight for all airlines to go to Argentina?

Tags: visas, airlines, buses, argentina, french-citizens

I am planning to travel through Latin America from the beginning of November onward. My first destination would be Buenos Aires. However, it seems most airlines need you to get a return flight so as to prove you will be staying no more than your visa allows you too. This is inconvenient as I will probably continue my travels by bus. Would a bus ticket suffice to show I will leave Argentina within 3 months? Is it possible to buy a one-way ticket and not run into problems travelling there?

Comment: Hi Emma,I hope you don't mind me asking for clarification:
From your description above, your question could be seen as "Can I get a single flight to Argentina?" or "Do I need to prove to authorities that I will leave the country within the time limit stated on my visa?"
Which one is the one you are trying to ask?

Comment: Is this for the purpose of preparing a visa ? Or simply being on the safe side with the airline at the airport ?

Comment: I was sure we had a question like this before, with the answer being "a return flight for elsewhere in South America (demonstrating intention to have already left Argentina) will do, but I can't find it anywhere in the argentina tag.

Comment: It's to be on the safe side with the airline. I am French so automatically get a tourist visa (meaning I can stay for 3 months). I've got the flight now. Do you think a bus ticket would suffice to prove I will leave within the 3 months? Thanks :)

Comment: [This](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/12805/9551), [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8245/entering-brazil-by-air-leaving-by-land-will-i-be-denied-entry) and [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7708/travelling-to-brazil-without-return-ticket) could be of interest to you.

Comment: @blackbird57 It seems the concern is more with airline requirements than entry requirements (the two are linked but airlines sometimes insist on things that aren't strictly required according to the law).

Answer (score 4):

In general, from all my travels, it has been very inconsistent. It varies from airline to airline and country to country. I don’t have an answer to your question, but have some alternative solutions.

Though your inquiry about a bus ticket is something I haven't investigated as it is not always easy to get a bus ticket over the internet in many countries. If you go that route specifically for BA, you could also do a ferry ticket to Uruguay. That I have gotten emailed before.

If one wanted to be safe and did not have set travel plans, typically, it was that one buys the expensive refundable airline ticket for onward or return travel - then goes to get a refund. There is a new service that was recently introduced which will let you "rent" a ticket for a small fee for 48 hours - [FlyOnward](https://flyonward.com/). This may be another option for you.

Comment: Details can be good too! :)  Especially for different airlines.

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer

After a bit of searching all I can say is it's conflicted. You can book a bus to be on the safe side, it lessens your chances of being refused but it's no guarantee either. As @user35350 mentioned, I remember I had to buy my bus tickets in Argentina as they were not available over the internet so keep that in mind.

### Long answer

**Consular answer**

*Paris embassy:*

I checked with the Argentine embassy and their answer was basically to check with the airline.

> Il faut voir cela avec votre compagnie aérienne. C'est elle qui est
>   suceptible de pas vous faire embarquer à l'aller si vous ne disposez
>   pas de billet de retour sous moins de trois mois. Veuillez donc
>   contacter votre compagnie aérienne.

*Montreal consulate:*

> If you are asked at the entry point, you have to prove that you will
>   be leaving the country in a true date. A ticket containing a date of
>   departure could be a proof of that. Note hat the decision to allow
>   entrance into a country -even if the traveler has a duly issued visa-
>   is taken by the immigration officer at the border, as wherever in the
>   word.

**Airline answer**

*Air Canada:*

> You'll have to contact Argentinian authorities as this is a customs
>   issue. We just make sure you have the correct documentation but the
>   local authorities make the decisions.

*Air France:*

> This need to be confirmed by the Argentinian consulate of your country
>   of residence.

*Delta:*

> All airlines require proof of onward/return travel, visitors not holding  return/onward tickets could be refused. A bus ticket is not considered onward/return travel

*Lufthansa:*

> As long as the names match exactly on the passport, flight and bus ticket, it counts as sufficient proof of onward travel

**Travel advisories**

US, Canadian and French governmental travel advisories don't mention anything about exit requirements for Argentina. The [UK](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/argentina/entry-requirements) has a note that some airlines have refused to board passengers without proof of onward travel, but they don't specify which kind.

> Proof of onward travel
>
> You may need to provide proof of onward travel in the form of a return
>   ticket. You should make all flight reservations before departing for
>   Argentina. Airlines have sometimes refused to board passengers
>   travelling to Argentina without proof of onward travel.

**Extra**

Most info regarding this on blogs mentioned people had no problem travelling without a proof of onward travel, however I don't know how reliable they are as they were from 2008-2010 so I'm only mentioning them.

[Here](http://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowTopic-g312741-i979-k3346923-Proof_on_onward_travel-Buenos_Aires_Capital_Federal_District.html), [here](http://www.travelsur.net/forum/messages/4/3192.html) and [here](http://www.livingthedreamrtw.com/2009/02/proof-of-onward-travel-part-1.html)

Comment: FWIW, when I entered Argentina on bus from Chile ~two months ago (though it was Santiago-Mendoza, so a rather different entry point), I had bought a return ticket (just to make sure I wouldn't get stuck at the border or something), but they didn't even ask about exit plans or request proof or anything.