# Is it possible to obtain a visa to Brazil without entry ticket?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, brazil

I have plans to meet a friend in Paris mid-September. Before that I will be visiting Brazil.  Therefore, I am considering buying a flight Brazil to France.  This should satisfy the proof-of-onward-travel requirement for my Brazilian visa.

However, before visiting Brazil, I will be spending some time in Mexico, and possibly Peru.  This means I don't yet know if I'll be flying to Brazil from Peru or Mexico, and I don't yet know which date I will be entering Brazil.

Is it possible, as a US citizen, to obtain my tourist visa to Brazil with only a departure date/ticket?  If not, can I purchase a (cheap) entry ticket into Brazil for an early date, will I be permitted entry if I enter on a later date?

Comment: so to clarify, you want to get a visa to Brazil, without having proof of arrival dates?
Usually you can arrive any date after the start of your visa, it's just valid for the whole, say, 30 days.

Comment: given that it's no doubt possible to enter Brazil by road or ship, I don't see why not. You might just have to provide a travel itinerary detailing those plans.

Comment: @MarkMayo: That's correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official answer appears to be **NO**.

I e-mailed the Brazilian Consulate in Houston, and this was their (ambiguous) response:

> Dear Sir/Madam,
>
> Tourist visa applications require the presentation of the itinerary.
>
> Please contact this office once you have certain plans.
>
> You don't have to present a purchased plane ticket. A round trip reservation under your name will suffice.

It seems clear to me this was a copy-and-paste answer, and wasn't intended to address my actual question of whether an entry reservation/booking was actually necessary.

But I suppose it's probably safest to have my full itenerary planned before I apply.